# LU-Factorization for strongly elliptic matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

For symmetric and positive matrices, we know that the cholesky factorization is stable. For a general matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ with
$$
Ax\cdot x \geq C_{ell}|x|^2\quad\text{for all }x\in \mathbb{R}^n
$$
for some $ C_{ell}> 0$, the LU-factorization exists, i.e. A=LU. My question is: Are there any estimates like
$$
\|L\|+\|U\|\leq C_{inv}( C_{ell}^{-1} + \| A\|),
$$
where $C_{inv}>0$ does not depend on the dimension $n\in\mathbb{N}$.